# Question marks instead of dashes

Tags: asp.net, email, .net-4.0, mailmessage

I have a program that runs on .NET.  A client is having a problem that appears to be an email encoding issue.  Question marks are showing up in the email body; I've changed the encoding to UTF.  Still a problem.

> CHARLOTTE, N.C. (AP) — The Republican National Committee is holding its winter meetings in the North Carolina city where Democrats re-nominated Barack Obama for president four months ago.

Shows up like this:

> CHARLOTTE, N.C. (AP) ??? The Republican National Committee is holding its winter meetings in the North Carolina city where Democrats re-nominated Barack Obama for president four months ago.

The encoding for the email message is set to UTF-8.

```
MailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

From the HTML header in the email:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Here is the really odd thing:

- The problem is happening on Windows and Mac
- I am subscribed to this list and the emails display fine on my end.
- I am running Outlook 2013 with Exchange 2010; they are on Outlook and some other programs, not sure which.

Could there be some security software installed that would mess this up?  Could UTF-16 work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because some email programs don't like [high ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) characters in HTML.  Convert all high ASCII characters to HTML equivalent.

Sloppy .NET version on StackOverflow: [More advanced .NET HTML Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485301/more-advanced-net-html-encoding/14492899#14492899)

Also more on HTML and ASCII: [Sonic's Ultimate HTML Character Set pages](http://www.siber-sonic.com/mac/charsetstuff/Soniccharset.html#tables)