# More advanced .NET HTML Encoding

Tags: asp.net, html-email, mailmessage

I am looking for an HTML encoder that is a little more thorough than .NET's HtmlEncode method.  That method will handle <> but not long dashes, which is causing me problems.  Is there a .NET library out there that encodes all special characters into HTML?

Where this:

> CHARLOTTE, N.C. (AP) — The Republican National Committee is holding its winter meetings in the North Carolina city where Democrats re-nominated Barack Obama for president four months ago.

Would translate into:

> CHARLOTTE, N.C. (AP) &mdash ; The Republican National Committee is
>   holding its winter meetings in the North Carolina city where Democrats
>   re-nominated Barack Obama for president four months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a poor man's HTML encoder I found somewhere online.  This uses .NET's HtmlEncode function and then takes all "High ASCII" characters and converts them to the HTML equivalent &# 000;.  Sloppy but effective.

```
        public static string HtmlEncode(this string input)
    {
        char[] chars = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(input).ToCharArray();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(input.Length + (int)(input.Length * 0.1));

        foreach (char c in chars)
        {
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(c);
            if (value > 127)
                result.AppendFormat("&#{0};", value);
            else
                result.Append(c);
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```